# Adding the id to the html code generated by p:messages

Tags: primefaces

I need to add an attribute html "id" for each "li" with an error message generated by PrimeFaces.

When writing code:

```
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="false"
                        closable="false" escape="true" />
```

I get:

```
<div id="messages">
<ul>
    <li>msg1</li>
    <li>msg2</li>
</ul>
```

and I need:

```
<div id="messages">
    <ul>
        <li id="id1">msg1</li>
        <li id="id2">msg2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why? The only way this can be done is by changing the source of PF or by really ugly complex hacks. And btw, this is 'illegal' html... 2 identical id's?

Comment: So unfortunately I made this. It's a mistake ... it should be id2

Comment: But still, the 'why' remains...

Comment: We use automated testing tool that without the "id" can not cope

Comment: write your own custom renderer

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar Thanks!